# iPhone connected to charger and shows charging but not charging battery

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

Last night I charged up my iPhone 5c and this morning I woke up and it was on 1 percent. After this, I checked that the iPhone's charger was plugged in properly and it looked fine.

I turned on my phone to answer a message and the phone went dead. I don't understand why this happened because it had the lightning bolt there in the battery, indicating it was charging.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me once. Your charger is an Apple charger? When I was using a fake charger it was a really problem for me, so my way to fix it was rebooting via **LOCK + HOME** buttons and then check if the iPhone was charging. It could be just a bug.

If it's still not charging, change your charger because it can be broke somewhere or getting voltage changes. Apple Support have all the graphics for voltage changes with fake wires or chargers.